# Cannot get SQL Server 2008 Express R2 to get through firewall

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, sql-server-2008

Try as I might I cannot get remote access to my install of SQL Server. I know the firewall (Windows Server 2008) is the problem, since if I drop the firewall I can connect fine. I have the port open in the firewall but still no connection. It's driving me crazy, am I miss something really obvious?

I've double checked that the port I specified is the one used to get the connection, but it's as if the firewall is just ignoring my exception...

Answer (score 1):

Just to check, you are using TCP port 3389 (default of RDP), right? What scope do you have the firewall rule under? If you defined the FW rule for a different scope than the OS thinks it is coming from, it won't match it. ie, if the network adapter is on a "public" scope and the rule you put in is for a "domain" scope, it won't match.

EDIT: Doh. Just realized I misread that - I thought you said remote desktop. Do you have both 1433 and 1434 UDP opened up?

Comment: I've set SQL Server to be listening on 2775, so I've opened the following ports: 2775, 1433, 1434 and 3389. All have their scope set to 'Any computer'. Still no connection through the firewall. I am connected to a domain, could this be relevant?

Comment: What about on the "Advanced" tab of the firewall rule.. which profiles are selected? Does the SQL server only have one network interface?

Comment: Set to [tick]Local Area Connection. The server is a VM, only has one network connection.

Comment: And under that Advanced tab, which profiles are selected?

Comment: Firewall Settings > Advanced tab > just one Network connection listed, Local Area Connection (selected)

Comment: What about the profile, not network connection. See this screenshot: http://img253.imageshack.us/img253/8986/profilesu.png

Comment: Cheers Dan, I'll check that when I'm back in the office tomorrow.

Comment: OK, my rule for port 2775 was set to Domain. The other rules I created were set to various combinations. I set all the rules to 'All profiles' and I still can't get a connection. Is MySQL any good? (~_^)

Comment: A potentially easier option might be to allow access for the Sqlservr.exe process (and the sqlbrowser.exe process). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx

Comment: Tried that too. In the end I couldn't spend any more time trying to get it to work, so I've had to turn off the firewall totally (v. bad I know, but I'm on a secure network so should be okay). I know I'm just putting of the inevitable and at some point I'll have to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your full rule? We're kind of grasping at straws here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting via Named Pipes or TCP/IP? TCP/IP will require port 1433, but Named Pipes use the standard Windows RPC mechanism and require ports 139 and 445 to be open.

Answer (score 0):

Do you created an **inbound** rule for port TCP 1433? I have the same problem a few days ago at work because I created by mistake an outbound rule (I didn't realize that until the next day...).

Also, if your server don't use the default instance (e.g. you access the server using `servername\instance` instead of jus `servername`), you need to allow access to the SQL Server Browser too (UPD 1434).